# Moving blog articles location in Middleman

Tags: ruby, blogs, middleman

I'm using the Middleman Blog gem for my site, but by default it appears the blog articles need to be located in `/source` which isn't particularly nice when looking at the tree in vim and trying to locate one of the other files in there (a template for instance).

From looking at the documentation I can't see if there is any way of moving the blog articles so they are stored somewhere else such as a `blog_articles` folder or similar.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the following in your config.rb file.

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.permalink = ":year-:month-:day-:title.html"
  blog.sources = "blog_articles/:title.html"
end
```

Assuming you have a post `2012-01-01-example-article.html.markdown` stored in the folder `source/blog_articles`.

You should now see the post with this URL: `http://localhost:4567/2012-01-01-example-article.html`. (You might have to restart middleman when changing the `config.rb` file.)

Please note that I also had to set `blog.permalink`, the `blog.sources` setting alone didn't do the trick.

A bonus tip: I have `activate :directory_indexes` in my `config.rb` file. This setting gives you nice looking URLs, without the `.html` part.
If you want the same for your blog posts you can drop the `.html` from your `blog.permalink`setting. Like so:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.permalink = ":year-:month-:day-:title"
  blog.sources = "blog_articles/:title.html"
end
```

Now you can see your post with this URL: `http://localhost:4567/2012-01-01-example-article`.

Comment: This failed for me with latest middleman and rails 4, the feed.xml fails and it still writes to /posts/* the blogposts

Answer (score 0):

I messed with the middleman-blog extension, but gave up for its relative opaqueness. In looking at [the source](https://github.com/middleman/middleman-blog/blob/master/lib/middleman-blog/extension.rb#L79-L87), though, it appears the `prefix` option might do the trick for you? It's somewhat unclear whether the prefix is a URL prefix or a local path prefix:

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.prefix = "/blog_articles"
end
```

Comment: Hmm, odd. The source seems to be loading from a File object which made me think it would suit the purpose here. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code it transpires there is a `:sources` option which you can use.  If you poke around in the source there is an example of this:

https://github.com/middleman/middleman-blog/tree/master/fixtures/article-dirs-app

Comment: I saw that, but was confused as the default `:sources` option seems to be more about the filename format: `options.sources              ||= ":year-:month-:day-:title.html"`.

Comment: Same here, it wasn't until I saw the fixture prefixed with a folder did the light bulb go on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above worked for me when I made the following changes to the permalink / source config options:

```
blog.permalink = ":title.html"
blog.sources   = "posts/:year-:month-:day-:title.html"
```

The permalink is the location which it will appear in the web browser url where the source is the locations of the posts.

Using middleman 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I made blog folder inside source directory. Then i make posts directory and moved all my posts there. source/blog/posts/...

and then inside config.rb

```
activate :blog do |blog|
..........
  blog.permalink = "blog/:year/:month/:day/:title.html"
  blog.sources = "blog/posts/:year-:month-:day-:title.html"
  .........
end
```

Comment: Now all the urls are prefixed with /blog